# Audio not transferring from USB in Oppo A53

Tags: usb, audio, kernel

I have Oppo A53. The 3.5mm jack did not work properly so I bought a USB type C to 3.5mm converter, but this is also not working with my phone which is running on Android 12.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have sound without having something plugged in into the headphone jack and the usb-c socket?

Answer (score 0):

Note that not all devices and/or converter dongles play nice.  Here's an excerpt from an [article](https://www.cablematters.com/Blog/USB-C/usb-c-audio#:%7E:text=Not%20every%20USB%2DC%20audio,devices%20as%20active%20or%20passive.) by CableMatters.com to this regard:

> ...The biggest problem with USB-C audio is its lack of standardization, which is ironic considering USB-C’s purpose is to standardize USB connection types. The problem lies not with the USB-C specification, but with the companies that design smartphones, dongles, and headphones. Here’s why this can be such a confusing mess: (Note that the remainder of this article will only reference USB-C headphones. Keep in mind that the same principles apply to USB-C dongles as well.)
> Some smartphones send audio data through an onboard DAC (usually embedded in the phone’s processor) before sending it out through the USB-C port. If this is the case, almost any pair of USB-C headphones will work. If the audio stream is converted to an analog signal before it goes through the USB-C port, then connected headphones do not need their own DAC. These are known as “passive” headphones.
> However, some devices send audio data through the USB-C port as a digital signal. As such, connected headphones will need their own onboard DAC and amp to convert the audio stream from a digital format to an analog format. USB-C headphones with an onboard DAC/amp combination are known as “active” headphones...

Also note, there may be configuration-side factors to consider, e.g., the `Disable USB audio routing` setting in developer options (formerly known as `allow USB audio pass-through`, if I remember correctly).  This may vary depending on your specific make, model, and Android version.